Customer Artifacts not getting generated for XCUITest on AWS Devicefarm
I was trying to run the default app-launch XCUITest on AWS Devicefarm programmatically(via bash script). As told in the documentation, I created the ipa file for app and test Runner and uploaded it to AWS devicefarm. For Test Spec, I used the default testspec provided by the AWS. The tests ran properly but when I tried to fetch the results, the xcresult file was not generated properly. I checked for the logs as well and it stated the following error:
Failed to copy some or all files from $DEVICEFARM_DERIVED_DATA_PATH

Can someone help me to identify what the issue is? Thanks
I tried to run to upload the script through console and it successfully generated the xcresult file after running the tests successfully. Later I tried to change the TestSpec.yml file as well to run only a single test. But, when I try to run the test programmatically, the problem still persists.
